# My script is unable to click on a certain grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to get some information from  a webpage. To reach the content it is necessary to hurdle few steps, as in `accepting condition`, `fill in the inputbox`, `click on the search button` to populate results and finally click on `the first grid` (the first tr, more specifically) within the populated table. As soon as any click is initiated on `the first tr`, a new page (containing desired information) opens up.

My script can do the first three steps successfully. What I can't do are:

1. `perform a click on the first tr`
2. `focus to the newly opened tab` (containing information I'm after)

> To reach the content:
>
> This is [the link](https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName) to follow. There is an accept button to click first. Then there is an inputbox `Name` to be filled in with `HMC DESIGN GROUP`. Now, pressing the search button, the result should appear below within a table. From there I need to click on the first tr.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
link = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName"

def get_information(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnButton"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"SearchOnName"))).send_keys("HMC DESIGN GROUP")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnSearch"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".t-grid-content table tr"))).click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_information(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Currently the script neither clicks on the grid `the first tr of the newly generated table` nor throws any error. It quits the browser gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another `table` under the `div` with the same class name `"t-grid-content"`. It appears as `"Loading..."`. So after you submit the search you really make a click on node with selector `".t-grid-content table tr"`, but it just don't make a proper effect

You just need more specific selector.

Try, for instance

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]")))
```

To switch to new window, try update your function body as

```
driver.get(url)
current = driver.current_window_handle
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnButton"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"SearchOnName"))).send_keys("HMC DESIGN GROUP")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnSearch"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]"))).click()
driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0])
```

Comment: worked like magic sir. I had another question in my post: how can i switch to newyly opened tab? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Andersson : As OP stated that he wants to click on first tr , so clicking on middle of tr would make much sense, and we can give him css selector instead of xpath though.

Comment: @cruisepandey , I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `"//td[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]"` returns the table cell from a first `tr`.

Comment: that is fine. but you are looking for an element in searched name column, right ? All I am saying is to look for full tr and then click on middle of it (default clicking would be performed on middle though) . So giving him the full tr row would make much sense IMO.

Comment: Actually simple change from `"//td[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]"` to `"//tr[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]"` will do the trick

Comment: Yes, I tried and found it working just great. One last thing to know: should I use switch to default content or something when it is done. A oneliner comment will be very helpful. Thanks again for your fruitful effort sir.

Comment: Yes. When all required actions on new page are done use `driver.close()` to close new window and `driver.switch_to.default_content()` to get back to main screen

Comment: @Topto , sorry, you actually need `driver.switch_to.window(current)` as `driver.switch_to.default_content()` is used to get back from iframe

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this **css selctor** :

```
.t-grid-content table tr
```

to **this** :

```
.t-grid-content table tr.t-state-selected:first-child
```

for clicking on first **tr**.

Before clicking on first tr,  store the window handle as :

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
```

after clicking on first tr, store the window handle of newly opened window as:

```
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
```

Now all you have to do is to switch the focus of your web driver to newly opened windows.Like this :

```
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
```

Comment: I tried (several times) with you selector but It could not initiate the click. As you knew already that when a click is successfully performed, a new tab opens up.