# Can't make my scraper complete the loop to use up all the keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to get some information from a webpage. To get the content it is necessary to do some clicks and fill in an inputbox to produce the result. The result gets displayed in a new tab. So, it is necessary to switch to that particular window to parse the information. My script can do all this very efficiently.

It's a follow-up post of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346347/my-script-is-unable-to-click-on-a-certain-grid).

The problem I'm facing is that I'm using few keywords to get information from. When a single keyword is used then `driver.close()` might do the trick but I'm using multiple keywords so when I use `driver.close()`, there is no more window left to move along.

Question: how can I make the scraper close the `new tab` (when it grabs information from there) and switch back to main window to do the process cyclically until there is no more keyword to check?

This is my script so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://officialrecords.broward.org/AcclaimWeb/search/SearchTypeName"

def get_information(driver,url):
    for keyword in ['HMC DESIGN GROUP','HMC DESIGN GROUP']:
        driver.get(url)
        current = driver.current_window_handle
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnButton"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"SearchOnName"))).send_keys(keyword)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnSearch"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(., 'HMC DESIGN GROUP')]"))).click()
        wait.until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
        driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0])
        for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".listDocDetails"))):
            print(items.text)
        # driver.switch_to.default_content()
        # driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_information(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement below solution:

```
def get_information(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    current = driver.current_window_handle
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnButton"))).click()
    for keyword in ['HMC DESIGN GROUP','HMC DESIGN GROUP']:
        input_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"SearchOnName")))
        input_field.clear()
        input_field.send_keys(keyword)
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "btnSearch"))).click()
        wait.until_not(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "SearchingWaitImg")))
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(., '%s')]" % keyword))).click()
        driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0])
        for items in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".listDocDetails"))):
            print(items.text)
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(current)
```

Comment: I'm gonna give you a feedback as soon as I'm done testing, sir.

Comment: The line containing `SearchingWaitImg` was causing trouble for the first few times. Now, it works.